# python missing with removing firsts line python

Tags: python

```
def MyFunction(self):
    link = urllib.request.urlopen('https://tmall.aliexpress.com/item/LED-TV-Fusion-32-FLTV-32C100T/32825513034.html?spm=a2g02.8535951.s5a6899.1.5ae125bcprIpJn')

    lines = []
    for line in link.readlines():
        # взяли все строки с сотрудниками
        # Каждый сотрудник начинается с тегов <li><a href .....
        if line.find(b'src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf') != -1 and line.find(b'data-role') != -1:
            lines.append(line)



    link.close()

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = str(lines[i]).replace('  ','')

        spl=[]
        spl = str(lines[i]).split('https://')
        for i in range (len(spl)):
            if 'jpg' not in spl[i]:
                spl[i]=''
            if 'bigpic' in spl[i] :
                big = []

                big = spl[i].split('bigpic')
                spl[i]=''
                for j in range(len(big)):
                    print(big[j])
            s=spl[i]

            spl[i] = s[:s.find('jpg')+3 ]
            s = spl[i].find('ttle')

            print(spl[i])
```

I dont know what to do for removing all characters in the line starting from 'title' and to end of line. I've tried all methods. Please help me.
Program should parse images from aliexpress and give me urls.

Comment: Have you mispelled 'title' in the second to last line?

Comment: `spl[i].replace(spl[i][spl[i].find('title'):],'')`

Comment: code gives expected output when I run it, http://i.imgur.com/osgsCvt.png

Comment: spl replase didn't help me, output also giving me title and blabla after him